# What is the best way to debug the processElement part of the DoFn in dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I am struggling with debugging my codes under processElement of DoFn in dataflow. I don't think I can step through this part, since it will start multiple threads and run even on my local machine (DirectRunner), any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

So you did not give any information on your environment. First, I see differences between beam-sdk and Versions < 2. 
When using version 1.9.0 and running with DirectRunner and debug-mode in Eclipse, one can simply set a breakpoint inside the DoFn and you can debug as usual. With the beam-version, for now, I wasn't able to debug inside DoFn. Perhaps this helps you.

Comment: do you mean cloud dataflow SDK 1.9 vs beam SDK >2.0 ?

Comment: yes, with the SDK < 2 (Google intern) I can debug inside DoFns when running locally, but with the Apache Beam SDKs I didn't manage to do this in the same way. But I have to say, I didn't do much with the Apache Beam SDKs

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is make sure only a single input is going to enter the pipeline thus running your code only once.
For example if your pipeline reads from PubSub you can register to a DEV subscription when debugging and send a single message to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Press F9 which is resume program in intellij and F8 in Eclipse/STS